# Using AngularJS html5mode with express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

Client-side:

```
when("/page/:id", {
    templateUrl: "partials/note-tpl.html",
    controller : "AppPageController"
 });

$locationProvider.html5Mode( true );
```

Html:

```
<a ng-href="/page/{{Page._id}}">{{Page.name}}</a>
```

Server-side:

```
app.use("/page/:id", function( req, res ) {
 res.send( req.params )
});
```

As a result I get empty page or just object with id. What's wrong?
Angular does not load note-tpl.html template

Answer (score 0):

Might be because of the conflict from express templating engine vs angular.

What view engine are you using?

The use of {{}} might be handled by express and not angular. You can either change the server view engine to use other keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your server is not responding with note-tpl.html.

Are you sure your partials exist at that path? Have you used express.static?

Can help more with any error messages you get.